# Does an associate professor work in the laboratory on a daily basis?

Tags: professorship, working-time, associate-professor

I got a position as an associate professor at new university. I observe my colleagues that they do not work in the lab normally which is quite strange for me. In my previous job as assistant professor I needed to work hard myself in the lab to produce the results, then describe them and publish. Here I am generally ''forced'' to sit in front of computer but without going to the lab and work physically I do not produce any results and no publications... How it looks at your university? Life science field.

Comment: What is your field? "Lab" can mean different things.

Comment: Some do, some don't. This  "sit in front of the computer" is not related to research?  It seems your new employer hired you to do that stuff, and not to do research.  Talk to your chairman about this.  Ask whether you are supposed to do research, and if so how.

Comment: @Buffy - lab meaning life science field. Standard analytical lab with chemicals and biological things.

Comment: @GEdgar, you could probably expand that a bit to an answer.

Comment: @GEdgar - I am supposed to do the research, but I do not know how to do it without sitting in the lab. I do not want to ask my colleagues because they could feel offended.

Comment: What "force" is applied? How are you forced to sit...?

Comment: It is not a mobbing etc. :) I just do not have any training in the lab, I do not know the procedures of buying new things to do the research, I do not know whether I could use the equipment or not. There are other associate professors but I see that do not go to the lab.

Comment: @MarcinK Hmm, I've written my answer before seeing this last comment. Are you not an independent researcher as an associate professor? Is this not *your own* equipment? What sort of training do you require at this point of your career? Do you have money to spend? If so, how long have you gone without asking someone in the office for the procedures to spend that money?

Comment: "The lab"? Is it somehow a "common lab" for the entire department/group? Is it "owned/run/funded" by the department, as opposed to an individual PI (Principal Investigator) or team? Can you clarify?

Comment: @BryanKrause I am independent but I do not have my own lab. There is only one lab for the whole department where work students of 5 associate professors and one full. I am not allowed to use even HPLC before the training from technician (odd), but I was not trained in that way. I have a very little money to spend like 15k dollars and it is over 8 months working here. I have bought some chemicals for my M.Sc. student.

Comment: @paulgarrett - there is only one common lab for the whole department (5 associate prof + one full)

Comment: @MarcinK I think it's pretty usual to have a training procedure for shared lab equipment, since its not yours. Someone is responsible for maintaining it and they want to make sure it's in the best shape for everyone. It might seem tedious if you're already familiar but in that case I'm guessing the training will go quick. If you need to use the machine, what are you waiting for? I guess I'm not really sure what you're looking for here, I don't see anyone forcing you to sit in front of a computer, it seems more like you don't want to take any steps to move your work forward.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience in (neuro)biology this is largely a function of the size of the lab, particularly the number of students.

The tasks of writing papers and enough grant applications to support the lab (along with all the other tasks professors do: on administrative committees, reviewing grants and papers written by others, teaching responsibilities) take up a lot of a professor's research time, at any level.

The larger the lab, the more time moves from "bench time" to "supervising time". This is the delegation of responsibilities problem experienced by managers of all types, and also applies to professors.

It is more common for early-career professors to spend more time on the bench because they will have few students/postdocs and those students will be new students as well. As a lab matures, not only are more of the bench tasks done by students, but there are more senior students and postdocs that are familiar with work in the lab and can begin to mentor others on their bench skills.

I've also seen a lot of senior professors, who may be wary of taking on students as they approach retirement and have less career pressure, migrate back to their labs.

If your lab isn't productive without you in it, then you need to get back to the lab, regardless of how your colleagues' time is allocated. Probably more importantly, if you don't have students and postdocs in your lab that you are supervising, you're missing out on a big chunk of your job which is to train the next generation of scientists.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this makes sense to you. It isn't my field. I'm just thinking about what I would do if I found myself in a completely foreign environment. I think you have some freedom to do what you want as an associate professor, even if that doesn't imply tenure in your place as it would in the US, though you don't say where you are.

I would spend some time wandering around and talking to people about what they do. Some of that time would be spent in the lab talking to whoever is there, whether post-docs, grad students, technicians, etc. Ask about how what they do relates to the research they are involved in.

But spend some time, also, talking to other faculty members about their own research process. Explain, probably, that your previous experience seems more "hands-on" that what you see here.

Hopefully it will click. I'm guessing that your colleagues spend more time on supervision and on planning for future experiments than on carrying them out themselves. I don't know, but they will. Maybe you can enter into a collaboration with one or more of them to help you get into the local culture and how it operates.

You just landed on the moon. How do moon-lings operate? They know, ask and watch. Then try it out.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question one needs more context. Overall, it depends on the field, the higher education landscape in your country, the university, and the lab.

From experience I'd say the more senior (not biological age but hierarchy) you get the less time you will spend in a lab. Over time, you will have more and more administrative duties that take away from your time to do research. At the same time, you may hav more grants and projects and thus PhD students and postdocs to work together with you. So while you may spend less time in the lab you should still be able to have the same if not a higher research output but simply in a different role.